# Python: Inheriting methods of a parent class without being a child of the class

Tags: python

I can't seem to find information regarding what I'm trying to do, so I'm afraid the answer is "you can't do it" or "that's bad practice." But, here it goes:

Given the following:

```
Class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def methoda(self):
    return 1

Class C(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def methodc(self):
    return 2

import A, C
Class B(object):
  def __init__(self, classC):
    A.__init__(self)
      if classC:
         C.__init__(self)
  def methodb(self):
    return 2
```

Obviously, running:

```
b = A() 
b.methoda()
```

Is going to crash with an error:

```
Unbound method __init()___ must be called with A class as first argument (got B instance instead)
```

However, I am basically looking for a way to make this work. My motivation:

There are classes (maybe in the future) that will duplicate a certain group of methods (say some fancy conversions). In an effort to reduce code, I'd like for the future classes to inherit the methods; but for legacy reasons, I don't want B to inherit C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple solutions:

Don't use special methods directly:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._init(self)
    @staticmethod
    def _init(self):
        ...actual initialization code here...
    def methoda(self):
        return 1

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._init(self)
    @staticmethod
    def _init(self):
        ...actual initialization code here...
    def methodc(self):
        return 2

import A, C
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, classC):
        A._init(self)
        if classC:
            C._init(self)
    def methodb(self):
        return 2
```

Or silly hacks involving copying from initialized objects:

```
import A, C
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, classC):
        vars(self).update(vars(A()))
        if classC:
            vars(self).update(vars(C()))
    def methodb(self):
        return 2
```

Note that none of these solutions will give access to methods from `A` or `C` on instances of `B`. That's just ugly. If you really need inheritance, use inheritance, don't do terrible things trying to simulate it poorly.

Comment: In your first example, would b.methoda() (nevermind, you made a ninja edit)

Comment: Sorry, realized I should clarify before you posted. :-) If you actually wanted to copy specific methods, you can always do that, e.g. inside the definition of `B`, do `methoda = A.methoda`, but if the invariants that method assumes don't hold, it's going to break.

Comment: So, let's say I change it to `B(A, C)`, is it possible to conditionally `__init__` C? Seems what I've read (`super(B, self).__init__()`) would run both `A.__init__()` and `C.__init__()`. Sorry about the ninja edits. It's been a long time since I've use SO, I have to relearn the formatting.

Comment: @Jason: The way to conditionally perform the `__init__` would be to have a separate subclass of `B` (where `B` extends only `A`) that also extends `C` and use that when appropriate instead of trying to make `B` a "sometimes subclass" of `C`. :-)

Comment: Makes since. I think my solution is going to be `B(A, C)` where the `A.__init__()` and `C.__init__()` are blank and then I go back and conditionally run something like `C._init2()`. From a IDE perspective, this is probably the most appropriate as well. (Why does my "@ShadowRanger" keep going away?)

Comment: I marked it as best answer, I've posted my own answer that shows what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just inheriting multiple classes. It's not exactly the way I wanted it done, but it's cleaner and easier for the IDE to follow

```
Class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    pass
  def methoda(self):
    return 1

Class C(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(C, self).__init__()
  def _C_init(self):
    # some init stuff
    pass
  def methodc(self):
    return 1

Class B(A, C):
  def __init__(self, use_C):
    super(B, self).__init__()
    if use_C:
      self._C_init()
  def methodb(self):
    return 2
```